# Android get users location

Tags: android, android-location

I am building an application which requires to get users location. Since I don't have very big experience with android, I am now reading information on how to get things working.

I have created a test application for learning purposes.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    latitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
    longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null) {
        onLocationChanged(location);
    } else {
        latitudeField.setText("Latitute not available");
        longitudeField.setText("Longitude not available");
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
    int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
    latitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
    longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
}
```

But I read that using `getLastKnownLocation()` isn't the best way because if you put your phone to sleep, go to another city than you won't get your location updates.
What would you suggest to use instead?

Comment: you are updating the request. Then when you chnage the location the automatically trigger your onLocationChnaged(). So in that way your location latitude and longitude changed

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't quite understand you...

Comment: You have overridden the onLocationChanged method which triggers when your location changes. In other words you will get updates even after you phone has been put to sleep.

Comment: @Karlis, isn't your problem solved yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to use **[GPSTracker](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/)**. Even though you put your mobile on sleep or  turn off/on your phone, this will give you absolute location as you require.